# What does $X^{−1}$ mean in in random variables?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

What is the meaning of $X^{−1}$ as in $X^{−1} (B) ⊂ A$ in random variables?

Comment: It means $\{ \omega | X(\omega) \in B \}$.

Answer (score 2):

Random variables are just functions (in a special context), so it means the same as it would for functions: for a random variable or function $X : A\to S$, and $B \subseteq S$,

$$X^{-1}(B) = \{ \omega \in A \mid X(\omega) \in B \}$$

Comment: Thanks. So it is an inverse function. Can you share a bibliography on this topic?

Comment: It's not an inverse function, but a preimage or pullback or fiber, depending on the context and what people like to call it. (But in each, it's not a function, but a set.) There isn't really anything to say on a "bibliography"; this is a common convention you should have learned from a more basic set-theory or proof-writing class, so consult your favorite set-theoretic resource.